# Will Spring estabilish connection to DB, when I use transacional bean in non-transacional?

Tags: java, spring

Good day, guys!

If I have non-transactional bean(BannerSizeServiceUntransact), which uses transactional bean(bannerSizeService), will Spring estabilish connection to DB, when I use non-transacional bean?
(I have many refused connections to PostgreSQL in log. I belive my logic does;t create new connection on each request, but may be I wrong.)

```
@Repository
public class BannerSizeServiceUntransactImpl implements BannerSizeServiceUntransact  {

    @Resource
    BannerSizeService bannerSizeService;


    public List<BannerSizeVO> sizesByType(String type) throws BannerServiceException{
        return bannerSizeService.sizesByType(type);

} }


@Repository
@Transactional
public class BannerSizeServiceImpl implements BannerSizeService {
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring will establish a database connection even when you're using beans that aren't marked `@Transactional`, so that's not the cause of your refused connections.

What's going to happen in this scenario is that when you invoke the call to `bannerSizeService.sizesByType(type)`, Spring will start a new transaction, and when control returns to `BannerSizeServiceUntransact.sizesByType()`, it will end.  So if `BannerSizeServiceUntransact.sizesByType()` did other database calls before or after the call to `bannerSizeService.sizesByType(type)`, those calls would happen in separate transactions, one per DB call.  (Not annotating a Service as `@Transactional` doesn't mean that transactions aren't used, just that they only span a single database call.)

Also note that if the method that calls `BannerSizeServiceUntransact.sizesByType()` was marked `@Transactional`, then the transaction started there will carry over all of the code you've shown here, because that transaction will start when that higher-up method is called and will end when it ends, and all of the code here will have executed while it was in effect.  Not annotating something as `@Transactional` doesn't forbid its participation in an existing transaction, it just doesn't require the initiation of a new one.

Also, keep in mind that `@Transactional` controls **transactions**.  Spring might end up making a new connection for each transaction it opens, or using only one and reusing it for each transaction, or rotating through a pool of connections (resulting in more than one but fewer than N connections for N transactions).  It's guaranteed that if Spring talks to the database, there will be a connection in use, but you can't guarantee how many will be used over N calls simply by your `@Transactional` annotations.  (Though of course you can set settings in your Spring config that might impact the number used, e.g. specifying a connection pool with a max size of 1.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer!

If I use @transactional bean, but don't execute SQL-queries in it, does it mean, that Spring estabilish empty connection?

Comment: Tim, can could you explain me, else one moment. When method executing in transactional bean, does this means, that all this time DB connection is active?

Comment: The `@Transactional` annotation will make Spring start a transaction, which is entirely in memory and doesn't create a database connection on its own.  When you make a call that would cause Spring to make a DB call (e.g. if you call get() if you're using Hibernate), or when Spring decides in the background that it's time to make a DB call (e.g. when it chooses to flush the Hibernate cache), then a DB connection will be made if one doesn't already exist for Spring to reuse.  But if your `@Transactional` bean's method doesn't do anything to interact with the DB, no connection will be made.